# Oracle SQL Query to join multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to join multiple tables and the below query works well.

```
select 
    e.ENCNTR_ID e_id
    , p.PERSON_ID p_id
    , e.REG_DT_TM admitted


from   
    episode e 
    , patient  p 
where (e.reg_dt_tm > '01/JAN/2018' 
       and e.reg_dt_tm < '02/JAN/2018' 
       and e.active_ind = 1
       and e.encntr_type_cd = 123.00 
       and e.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD = 1234 
       and e.person_id = p.person_id)
```

But when I change it and add more tables it gives me the error

> "SQL Command not properly ended"

I need to add conditions on the first table(episode) as otherwise the query runs very slow.

```
select 
    e.ENCNTR_ID e_id
    , p.PERSON_ID p_id
    , e.REG_DT_TM admitted
    , ce.EVENT_ID event_id

from   
    ENCOUNTER e 
    , person  p 
where (e.reg_dt_tm > '01/JAN/2018' 
       and e.reg_dt_tm < '02/JAN/2018' 
       and e.active_ind = 1
       and e.encntr_type_cd = 7113.00 
       and e.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD = 22223 
       and e.person_id = p.person_id)
left join CLINICAL_EVENT ce on ce.ENCNTR_ID = e.ENCNTR_ID      
                            and ce.EVENT_CD in (1235764 
                                                ,22161234 
                                                )                  
                            and ce.valid_until_dt_tm > sysdate
left join CE_BLOB cb on ce.EVENT_ID = cb.EVENT_ID
                    and cb.valid_until_dt_tm > sysdate

order by e.REG_DT_TM, ce.PERFORMED_DT_TM, ce.CLINICAL_EVENT_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
select e.ENCNTR_ID as e_id, p.PERSON_ID as p_id, e.REG_DT_TM as admitted, ce.EVENT_ID as event_id
from ENCOUNTER e join
     person p 
     on e.person_id = p.person_id left join
     CLINICAL_EVENT ce
     on ce.ENCNTR_ID = e.ENCNTR_ID and   
        ce.EVENT_CD in (1235764, 22161234) and                
        ce.valid_until_dt_tm > sysdate left join
     CE_BLOB cb
     on ce.EVENT_ID = cb.EVENT_ID and
        cb.valid_until_dt_tm > sysdate
where e.reg_dt_tm > date '2018-01-01' and
      e.reg_dt_tm < date '2018-01-02' and
      e.active_ind = 1 and
      e.encntr_type_cd = 7113.00 and
      e.ACTIVE_STATUS_CD = 22223 
order by e.REG_DT_TM, ce.PERFORMED_DT_TM, ce.CLINICAL_EVENT_ID;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- The `WHERE` clause goes after the `FROM` clause.
- `JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause, so all `JOIN`s need to be before the `WHERE`.
- Use the keyword `DATE` for date constants.

Comment: Thanks Gordon but I am still getting the same error. Sorry about the simple question. But I was just wanted SQL to run the date condition first before anything else as otherwise it takes longer but haven't been successful so far.

Comment: @NancyK . . . I don't see an obvious syntax error in this answer.

Comment: Rule #1 of SQL: You do not control the order of execution.  The RDBMS will choose the exact steps to execute and the order in which to execute them.  You simply describe what you need in the results and let Oracle do its thing.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I just missed something after the comment. I am used to writing CCL so missed the part. Can you confirm if I run the query it evaluates the date condition first and then goes further as that is the first condition in where.

Comment: Just read your comment. So I cant choose which table to go to first?